# Migrating Authentication from dotnet core 1.1 to dotnet core 2.0

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

We just migrated our authentication middleware from .net core 1.1 to .net core 2.0, following the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118528/3554176) answer. Everything builds and runs, however, when I try to make a request (even when trying to get to the Swagger UI) I get the following exception on my custom `AuthenticationHandler` called `UserAuthHandler`  :

`System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'BrokerAPI.AuthMiddleware.UserAuthHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.`

The code from `UserAuthHandler`:

```
public class UserAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions>    
{
    protected UserAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //handle authentication
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
           new AuthenticationProperties(), "UserAuth");

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

The code from `UserAuthExtensions`:

```
public static class UserAuthExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
    { 
        return builder.AddScheme<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions, UserAuthHandler>("UserAuth", "UserAuth", configureOptions);
    }
}
```

How I call everything in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "UserAuth";
            }).AddCustomAuth(o => { });
    }
public void Configure()
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

I have scavenged Google for examples and people with similar issues, but to no avail.

Am I missing something related to my DI-container? Or is it something related to Authentication in .net core 2 in general?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception message is actually really clear: your handler has a protected constructor that cannot be used by the dependency injection system. Make it public and it should work:

```
public class UserAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions>    
{
    public UserAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<UserAuthAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }
}
```