# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Dynamic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

When using `.AddOpenIdConnect()` within `ConfigureServices`, is it possible to change the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` based on the host from the request?

I know the `Startup` itself doesn't have access to the `HttpContext`, but I was wondering if using a middleware would solve this where it would have access to the context.

I've tried following the below link, however my values are always null after it runs through the CustomAuthHandler
[ASP.NET Core 2.0 authentication middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware)

Comment: The ClientId is used to identify your app. You don't need to change it, nor the password if you configure your oids server for multiple hosts.

Comment: I'm curious what is the motivation for this?

Comment: The purpose is for multi tenancy. Each tenant will have it's own auth provider account. Therefore, the id and secret will be different between tenants

Comment: Client login is typically for server to server communication. If you are hosting the app, how are you going to allow the tenant to use it? Does the tenant have to login for that? I think there are two scenarios: the tenant has its own app where clientid/secret must be used (configure multiple clients in the oidc server and set the right scope to access the resource), or the tenant is a user and logs in. In that case the user is identified and along with your apps credentials (which do not change and are kept secret!) the resource can be accessed.

Comment: For the user you use grant_type=password, while for the client you use grant_type=client_credentials. These are different flows.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg The project is using Auth0 as the login provider. It's using Cookies but. if a cookie doesn't exist, the user gets redirected to the Auth0 hosted login page. It only knows the correct Auth0 page based on id, secret and audience being set. Hence the need for it to change depending on the sub domain the user id navigating to.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Identity Server the tool for this? [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver.io/) it is design for multi tenancy. Another solution that comes to my mind is using databases or json files to get the data from there, if it depends on the host they are connecting from you can use an API that recognizes the host and then checks the db or json file to assign the client credentials

Comment: @FedeAntuña I do have a json config file. The issue is 'how' to update the clientId and clientSecret at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can achieve your goal assigning function to `RedirectToIdentityProvider` property.

> Invoked before redirecting to the identity provider to authenticate.
>   This can be used to set ProtocolMessage.State that will be persisted
>   through the authentication process. The ProtocolMessage can also be
>   used to add or customize parameters sent to the identity provider.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
             {
                  // Retrieve identity from current HttpContext
                  var identity = context.HttpContext.User.Identity;

                  // Lookup for your client_id and client_secret
                  var clientId = "find your client id";
                  var clientSecret = "find your client secret";

                  // Assign client_id and client_secret
                  context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = clientId;
                  context.ProtocolMessage.ClientSecret = clientSecret;

                  return Task.FromResult(0);
              };
         });
}
```

**Related links**

[OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onredirecttoidentityprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_OpenIdConnect_OpenIdConnectEvents_OnRedirectToIdentityProvider)

Comment: While this points me in the right direction, it's not the full answer. You also need to update the 'context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId' and the 'context.Options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience'. Otherwise you run into conflicts of info in the current request

Comment: Okay, I will update the answer to make it completely correct. Thanks for update.

Comment: @niko619 this implementation leaks a client secret.

Comment: @dropoutcoder I am getting this error message when changing the clientId and clientSecret dynamically
`Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'The specified authorization code cannot be used by this client application.', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.`

Comment: @Mahendran: It is most likely a problem with settings on the auth server side.