# How do you handle failure to authenticate user in a custom AuthenticationHandler?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a scenario where an app needs to authenticate a user by calling an API and sending a user token to verify user identity. I started working on a custom authentication handler based on the following tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/21/aspnet-core-3-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

[Tutorial 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware)

I have a very basic example which right now simply fails the authentication just to make sure it works:

```
public class SoleAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<SoleAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private readonly ISoleApiService _soleApiService;

    public SoleAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<SoleAuthenticationOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock, ISoleApiService soleApiService) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _soleApiService = soleApiService;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("You are not authorized to access this resource."));
    }
}
```

This works as intended, controller actions decorated with [Authorize] attribute are intercepted and 401 is thrown. My questions are the following:

1. How am I supposed to handle the 401 once it happens? For example let's say I want to redirect a user to a friendly page that says "you're not authorized please login". Is that something done in the handler or elsewhere? What is the proper process here? Looking at Microsoft docs for the [AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0) there is a method called BuildRedirectUri but providing that method with a uri does not really change anything - the page still returns a 401.
2. As it stands now in order for this to work I need to decorate controllers/actions with [Authorize] attribute. Is there a way to do this globally so that I don't have to specifically authorize each controller and/or action?

Comment: What are you using for the front end? If it's a SPA like Angular your front end should check the error status for a 401 and redirect

Comment: @raklos No it's a typical .net mvc website the only difference is that it works within a larger portal application and it calls portal's api to authenticate. If the portal does not authenticate you then I need the AuthorizationHandler to redirect to the portal login. That's really the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

We had/have the `customErrors` pages in ASP.NET web forms and MVC 5.x to redirect users automatically to the specified error pages when a certain statusCode is issued:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="error/notfound" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="error/forbidden" />
</customErrors>
```

Here in ASP.NET Core we can simulate these pages this way:

First add a new `ErrorController` to handle specific statusCodes (id's here) and then return custom views for different conditions:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;

        public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var logBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            var statusCodeReExecuteFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
            logBuilder.AppendLine($"Error {id} for {Request.Method} {statusCodeReExecuteFeature?.OriginalPath ?? Request.Path.Value}{Request.QueryString.Value}\n");

            var exceptionHandlerFeature = this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error != null)
            {
                var exception = exceptionHandlerFeature.Error;
                logBuilder.AppendLine($"<h1>Exception: {exception.Message}</h1>{exception.StackTrace}");
            }

            foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
            {
                var headerValues = string.Join(",", value: header.Value);
                logBuilder.AppendLine($"{header.Key}: {headerValues}");
            }
            _logger.LogError(logBuilder.ToString());

            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            switch (id.Value)
            {
                case 401:
                case 403:
                    return View("AccessDenied");
                case 404:
                    return View("NotFound");

                default:
                    return View("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it's time to connect this controller to the built-in error handling middlewares of ASP.NET Core:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/index/500");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/index/{0}");
```

About your second question, just [define your filter/Authorize attribute globally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution).

Comment: Yeah this is sort of the same setup that I have the only thing different is I don't have the app.UseExceptionHandler("") call because I have a single controller/action handling all errors. But when I wire up that custom authentication handler once the handler returns 401 nothing else fires. I'm starting to think that it might be the order of things in the startup pipeline.