# Net Core 6: Session ID Changes After Redirect to AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync()

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

:: Using A Custom DistributedCache (Redis Implementation) ::

On all `Redirect(url)` calls, the session changes. I know the official MS Docs says that `IAuthenticationHandler` "Created per request to handle authentication for a particular scheme". Meaning even redirects cause a new session

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync() { }
```

The issue I am having is that during the new session ALL CONTEXT is lost. Everything I saved in the Context (including the `ClaimsPrincipal` of the user) gets lost. I cannot even fetch transients or singletons attached to my service through:

```
var SessionProvider = Context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ISessionProvider)) as SessionProvider;
```

Because there is no context. Here is the implementation I followed::
[ASP.NET Core 2.0 authentication middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware)

Please guide me on any assistance on how to persist Session during `AuthenticationAysnc()` calls.

Edit :: Here is my service code

```
service.AddAuthentication(options => {
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "CoreAuthScheme";
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CoreAuthScheme";
  options.DefaultScheme = "CoreAuthScheme";
  }).AddCustomAuth(o => {})
```

And With Web App

```
//Register Session Security (Goes before Routing)
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution ::

Proper Implementation of these two library srcs are needed if you are using a custom IDistributedCache. Obviously The IDistributedCache here is Redis Implementation, but the same goes for SQL, and other DB caching (get the proper src implementation of IDistributedCache)

Session Management
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/Session/src

IDistributedCache (Redis)
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src

The reason why I was losing session is because the default implementation of DistributedSession uses Offsets and special encodings to process values returned from the IDistributedCache Redis I implemented. See below:

```
 DistributedSession.Deserialize(...)
            var expectedEntries = DeserializeNumFrom3Bytes(content);
        _sessionIdBytes = ReadBytes(content, IdByteCount);

        for (var i = 0; i < expectedEntries; i++)
        {
            var keyLength = DeserializeNumFrom2Bytes(content);
            var key = new EncodedKey(ReadBytes(content, keyLength));
            var dataLength = DeserializeNumFrom4Bytes(content);
            _store.SetValue(key, ReadBytes(content, dataLength));
        }
```

Once you have those two libraries properly sourced and implemented. Session Management Works :). AuthenticateAsync calls the Distributed Session which calls DistributedCache and data is properly serialized and deserialized

----------------------------------------------------------- alimaslax