# ASP.Net core 2: Default Authentication Scheme ignored

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build a custom AuthenticationHandler in ASP.Net Core 2. Following up topic like [ASP.NET Core 2.0 authentication middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware) and [Why is Asp.Net Core Authentication Scheme mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806052/why-is-asp-net-core-authentication-scheme-mandatory), I've created the specific classes. The registering happens like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema; 
        options.DefaultForbidScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
    }
).AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(Constants.NoOpSchema, "Custom Auth", o => { });
```

Everything works, if the specific controllers set the Scheme explicitely:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes= Constants.NoOpSchema)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IndividualsController : Controller
```

But I would like to not have to set the Schema, since it should get added dynamically. As soon as I remove the Scheme Property, like this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IndividualsController : Controller
```

It doesn't work anymore.

I would have hoped, that setting the DefaultScheme Properties does this job. Interesting enough, I didn't find any specific discussion about this topic.
Am I doing something wrong here or is my expected outcome wrong?

Edit: Thanks for the questions, it helped me a lot. It seems like mapping the DefaultScheme is using by the Authentication Middleware, which I only used, when the CustomAuthHandler was not in place. Therefore I had to add the AuthenticationMiddleware always.

Edit2: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. To enhance a bit my question: I'm adding the middleware as usual:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

Now I get into my Handler, which is looking like this:

```
public class NoOpAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<NoOpAuthOptions>
{
    public const string NoOpSchema = "NoOp";

    public NoOpAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<NoOpAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() => Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(Context.User, NoOpSchema)));
}
```

But even if I always return success, I get an 401. I think I have to dig deeper and kindahow set some Claims, but unfortunately, the Handlers from Microsoft are quite hard to analyze, since they contain a lot of Code.

Comment: Have you add `app.UseAuthentication()` in your middleware pipeline?

Comment: what error do you get when you remove `AuthenticationSchemes`?

Comment: What does CustomAuthHandler do?

Comment: i supose you know, but you can inherit the authorize attribute to avoid the AuthenticationSchemes= Constants.NoOpSchema

Answer (score 20):

**ASP.NET Core 2 Answer**

You have to set a default authorization policy tied to your authentication scheme:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
  options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(Constants.NoOpSchema)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
});
```

**ASP.NET Core 3 Answer**

In ASP.NET Core 3 things apparently changed a bit, so you would want to create an extension method to add your authentication handler:

```
public static class NoOpAuthExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddNoOpAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddNoOpAuth(NoOpAuthHandler.NoOpSchema, _ => { });
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddNoOpAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<NoOpAuthOptions> configureOptions)
        => builder.AddNoOpAuth(NoOpAuthHandler.NoOpSchema, configureOptions);
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddNoOpAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, Action<NoOpAuthOptions> configureOptions)
        => builder.AddNoOpAuth(authenticationScheme, null, configureOptions);
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddNoOpAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, string displayName, Action<NoOpAuthOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<NoOpAuthOptions, NoOpAuthHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
    }
}
```

And use it in your `ConfigureServices` method like this:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(NoOpAuthHandler.NoOpSchema)
  .AddNoOpAuth();
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` is actually for, but it's not for setting the default [Authorize] scheme.

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to modify the NoOp `HandleAuthenticateAsync` provided by the question asker to return a `GenericPrincipal` instead of the User from the Context. Doesn't feel safe to be creating a `GenericIdentity`, but okay for my no-auth non-production use case.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you have Authentication middleware in your pipeline and place it before MVC.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ///

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    ///
}
```

**UPDATE**

try using this code in `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method.

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
    AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, Scheme.Name);
    return AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket);
}
```

Comment: Another note, in .NET Core 3/5, make sure you have `app.UseAuthentication` BEFORE `app.UseAuthorization()`. There goes 2 hours of my day :)

Comment: @RenéSackers Dang you saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suffer this for hours, in my case problem was default AuthenticationMiddleware class.

More specifically;
If you set ClaimsPrincipal within custom middleware in your request pipeline like below;

`HttpContext.context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);`
this will override your default auth config settings,

What I did to solve; remove custom middleware and add `app.UseAuthentication();` in Configure section in Startup.cs, and Authorize attribute checks whatever set in config section as default;

Here is mine;

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

Comment: This answer helped me find that setting value of DefaultScheme does not work! What I needed was setting DefaultAuthenticateScheme to my scheme, so my custom authentication handler will be executed on every request weather controller action decorated with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = MyAuthenticationConstants.Scheme)] or even [Authorize] attributes

Answer (score 2):

in .NET Core 3.1, I had to manually add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` instead of a plain `[Authorize]` to endpoints in order for authentication to function as I'd expect. The following configuration change solved the issue:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
services.AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookie"
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Constants.NoOpSchema;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookie";
        }
    )
    .AddCookie("Cookie")
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(Constants.NoOpSchema, "Custom Auth", o => { });
```